# Serialize with Qt, deserialize without Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, deserialization

If I serialize a struct using `QDataStream` and send this via UDP,

is it possible to then deserialize it without Qt ?

Comment: Yes. As long as you know the format.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi Sure, senderApp will send a serialized-struct via UDP, et my ReceiverApp will have the .h of my struct

Comment: It should be fine then. Just keep in mind that data types can have different sizes on different platforms/compilers so prefer to use types that have a guaranteed size. Also keep in mind the endianess of the transmitting/receiving machine. I'm sure that I'm forgetting a number of other things but try it out and see what happens. QDataStream does not do anything special to force you to use it on both sides.

Comment: Keep in mind that some data structures within Qt are version dependent. Even if you know how to deserialize an object (E.g. QString), it might change when changing a version. [QDataStream::setVersion](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#setVersion)

Comment: what is your receiver? and what language are you writing it in?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to deserialize without using the Qt library, you would have to read the Qt serialization format which is described briefly [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html), and write the deserialization code yourself. And since this format is likely to change, you should use `setVersion` in the serializing application and stick into some version that you can implement deserialization code for it in the receiver.

I don't recommend doing this, as it may take you long time, and you may run into a lot of errors when implementing deserialization for primitives such as the [standard IEEE 754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) used in serializing float numbers or maybe errors that are caused by different endianness across devices, etc. . .

So, why reinventing the wheel? if you don't want to use Qt in your receiver, you can use a common serialization format. JSON for instance is widely supported in many programming languages, and it is [supported in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html). If you don't like something about JSON there are [lots of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats) to choose from.