# Sending Structure from TCP Client (NON QT) to TCP Server (QT)

Tags: qt, sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver, qtcpserver

This is my common header file.

```
/*Type of data being sent to HMI*/
enum HMIDataType{
    Climate = 0x12
};

#define MIN_DATA_CLIMATE 0x00000200u
#define MAX_DATA_CLIMATE 0x000002ffu

/*Types of Climate Data*/
enum enumClimateData
{
    //! @brief Driver temperature
    //! Type : float
    DP_DriverTemperature_Float = MIN_DATA_CLIMATE
};


/*Climate Data to be sent to HMI*/
struct ClimateData{
   enumClimateData type;
   struct{
       double ddata;
       int idata;
       bool bdata;
   }body;
};

/*HMI data to be sent*/
struct HMIData{
   HMIDataType type;
   struct{
       ClimateData climatedata;
   }body;
};
```

Sender application is a NON QT TCP Client sending the Data over TCP Socket

```
/* Creating Data */
HMIData data;
data.type = Climate;
data.body.climatedata.type = DP_DriverTemperature_Float;
data.body.climatedata.body.ddata = 12.23;
SendDataToHMI(&data);
```

Sending it:

```
void SendDataToHMI(HMIData * data)
{
    /* send the message line to the server */
    size_t n = write(sockfd, (char*)data, sizeof(HMIData));
    if (n < 0)
      printf("ERROR writing to socket");
}
```

In my QT based TCP Server However I am unable to get back the data structure.

Doesn't work:

```
HMIData* m= new HMIData();
// get the information
qint64 Data = socket->read((char*)m, sizeof(HMIData));
qDebug() << "Type: " << (uint)m->body.climatedata.type << "Data: " << m->body.climatedata.body.ddata;
```

Doesn't work:

```
QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

QDataStream dstream (Data);
HMIData m;
while(!dstream.atEnd())
{
    dstream >> m;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific, *Doesn't work* is **not** a good problem description. Also, sending `struct`s like that is not guaranteed to work. In your case, this depends on the internal representation of `int`, `double`, `bool` on each of the sender and the receiver (read about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) and also, on the structure layout your compiler have chosen to do.

Comment: These problems are exactly why [serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats) are used. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37477137/2666212).

Comment: Same Machine ... sending data from UBUNTU linux running on VmWare into QT code running in Windows. By doesn't work i mean except the first field which is coming correctly all other fields are junk values (big hexadecimal value for the embedded enum and negative value for the float)

Comment: This is the exact definition of different machines running different operating systems. Being a virtual machine on the same host does not have anything to do with *unifying endainness*. They are different operating systems, and each one of them is free to use its memory as it would normally do. Also, using different compilers, may cause different `struct` layout on both machines.